# How to clear last row content of google sheet by using of apps scrpt?

Tags: google-apps-script

Tried with the mentioned script but not working.

var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
sheet.getLastRow().clearContent()

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

```
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
var last_row = sheet.getLastRow();
var last_column = sheet.getLastColumn();
sheet.getRange(last_row, 1, 1, last_column).clearContent();
```

Comment: Thank you for your prompt support.